# Push Notification in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have developed mobile app using phonegap. I have some problem with push notifications. all I want is when I have update something new in mysql database and it alert to all client. and i found some example in git. but it is not as I want. and the notifications alert is not in status bar. as below image.
[This is image that i screenshot in my Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt4Xt.jpg)
[This is image that my push notification in php using wamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMLS8.png)
This is my project in git `https://github.com/khengsopheak/PushNotification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i saw your code in github u need to do some changes in GCMIntentService.java file for receive the json params from push.

Note:please use this code as reference i wrote this based on my app requirment

[image: My Json Response from push]

GCMIntentService.java

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, BHC.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("notify", true);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
        try {
            defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("alert"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("alert"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    Random random = new Random();
    int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    mNotificationManager.notify(m, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    LaunchState = "1";
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.bhc_splash_screen);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    // super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
    super.clearCache();

    JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
    appView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "android");

    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    // appView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "android");
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        this.appView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
    onNewIntent(getIntent());
}


protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {

    String strActivityId = "", strTypeName = "", strTypeId = "";
    if (intent.getExtras() != null
            && intent.getExtras().containsKey("notify")) {

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        // intent.getExtras().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Intent", intent.getExtras().toString());
        boolean isNotify = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("notify");
        Bundle bundle;
        if (isNotify) {
            bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("pushBundle");
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bundle"+
            // bundle.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            strActivityId = bundle.getString("ActivityID");
            strTypeName = bundle.getString("TypeName");
            strTypeId = bundle.getString("TypeID");

            Log.i("Alert", bundle.getString("alert"));
            Log.i("ActivityID", bundle.getString("ActivityID"));
            Log.i("TypeName", bundle.getString("TypeName"));
            Log.i("TypeID", bundle.getString("TypeID"));

            if (bundle != null) {
                if (LaunchState == "1") {
                    // appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#cat="+bundle.getString("category")+"&subcat="+bundle.getString("subcategory"));
                    // appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#activityid="+strActivityId+"&typename="+strTypeName+"&typeid="+strTypeId+"");
                    this.appView
                            .sendJavascript("javascript:pushNotificationFunction('"
                                    + strTypeId
                                    + "','"
                                    + strTypeName
                                    + "','" + strActivityId + "')");
                    LaunchState = "0";
                } else {
                    this.appView
                            .sendJavascript("javascript:pushNotificationFunction('"
                                    + strTypeId
                                    + "','"
                                    + strTypeName
                                    + "','" + strActivityId + "')");
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "else",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        LaunchState = "0";
    }

    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: thank you guy, I have change function as yours but for Mainactivity.java where should i add your code? public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

}